# Limiting Output of Knapsack Algorithm to specified bit-size

Tags: algorithm, encryption, cryptography

Currently, my professor has given a group assignment that requires us to take values from a simulated ECG scan and Quantize them to 8-bit values. From there we are to take the 8-bit values and run them through a knapsack encryption algorithm.

I have no problem with the coding, but rather a question of the Knapsack itself.

We are using a Super-increasing key to create our general key. We are supposed to come up with the SIK, m and n values. In this case I picked { 1, 2, 5, 9, 22, 43, 118, 207 } to be my SIK, since we are just using 8 bits. Also, my n=19, and my m=511 (i.e. 19*(whatever)mod511).

This generates the resulting General Knapsack:
{19, 38, 95, 171, 418, 306, 198, 356}

The problem comes when I encrypt a value. Say I encrypt something like 10010111
The resulting value would be 1050 (in decimal). Putting this value back into my Quantizer would be a problem, considering it is designed to turn decimal values into 8 bits binary, and this gives a 10-bit number.

So I played around with the values, changing the SIK to the smallest values possible and different variations of m and n, and still I get encrypted values that are greater than 8 bits.

**Essentially my question is this: Is there a value for m and n that I could use that would generate values in the desired bit range (8-bits), or is it mathematically impossible? The professor said he wasn't sure if it was possible, but he thought it was.**

I could convert the Quantizer to be able to take larger amount of bits, but was just curious to see if what he was asking was even possible.

Answer (score 1):

"*Is there a value for m and n that I could use that would generate values in the desired bit range (8-bits), or is it mathematically impossible?*"

Can't prove it impossible, but I will say from a practical point of view, it's not going to work.  Here's why.

Because of the super increasing property, each element being at least double the previous implies that the 8th element has to be >= 2^8 = 256.  As a consequence, your modulus `m` needs to be larger than 256, which is 9-bits.

Now for this to work, you need to find a value of `n` such that any subset sum of the generated knapsack to be at most 8-bits (255 is the largest value).  The worst case is 11111111, where all numbers are added together.  The elements in your generated knapsack are all on the same order as your modulus, which is at least 9-bits.  So you're looking at adding 8 elements that are only the order of 9-bits in hope that the total sum is 8-bits.  True, I haven't proven it impossible, but I hope it gives you a feeling for why this is unlikely to happen.